# Question on splitting fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $K$ be a field, $f(x)\in K[x]$ monic and irreducible polynomial
>   over $K[x]$, $E$ the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $K$ and $a,b\in E\
> $  two roots of $f(x)$.

We would like to prove that there exists a field automorphism $\eta: E\longrightarrow E$ such that $\eta(a)=b.$

**My attempt.** Let's take the field automorphism $Id_K:K\longrightarrow K$.

We observe that

1. $f(x)\in K[x]$ is monic, irreducible over $K$, and $f(a)=0_K$. So, $f(x)=Irr_{(K,a)}(x)$.
2. $f(x)\in K[x]$ is monic, irreducible over $K$, and $f(b)=0_K$. So, $f(x)=Irr_{(K,b)}(x)$.

So, $f(x)=Irr_{(K,a)}(x)=Irr_{(K,b)}(x)\in K[x].$ Also, since $E$ is the splitting field of $f(x)=Irr_{(K,a)}(x)\in K[x]$ over $K$ and $E$ is the splitting field of $Id_K (f(x))=f(x)=Irr_{(K,b)}(x)\in K[x]$ over $K$ there exists an automorphism 
$$\eta : E \longrightarrow E$$
that extends $Id_K$.

- Is this attempt in the right way?
- How do we prove that $\eta(a)=b$?

Thank you.

Comment: Settling your second bullet is the key. First construct an isomorphism $\eta:K(a)\to K(b)$ such that $\eta(a)=b$. Do you see why such a thing exists?. Then proceed along the lines of the proof of uniqueness of the splitting field (up to isomorphism) to lift this to an automorphism of $E$. You build one splitting field as an extension of $K(a)$ inside $E$ and the other as an extension of $K(b)$ inside $E$.